how do i evaluate health risk assessment method parameters
I am using USEPA health risk assessment method. Can I evaluate its parameters in R? most of researchers have used other softwares.
CDI = (CIRETEFED)/(BW*AT) this the formula I want to evaluate each parameters. Main idea is which parameter is mainly dominated  for health risk

I think, you have better chances for an helpful answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com
